# results of a sub table in the top level query

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Not sure how to title this so please feel free to retitle.

I have two tables with a one to many relationship.

Table1

```
|ID|NAME|...|
```

Table2

```
|ID|Table1_ID|StartDate|EndDate|
```

I am trying to write a query that given a date will return the following

```
|TABLE1.ID|TABLE1.NAME|are any rows of table 2 in date|
```

I have a one to many between table 1 and table 2. I want to pass in a date to the query. If any of the many relationships in table 2 have a start date < passed in date and an end date > passed in date or end date is null then I want column 3 of result to be true. Otherwide I want it to be false.

Consider the example

```
|ID|NAME|...|
| 1|APPLE| ...|
| 2|PEAR| ...|
```

Table2

```
|ID|Table1_ID|StartDate|EndDate|
|1|1|01-01-2014|null|
|2|1|01-01-2014|01-02-2014|
|3|2|01-01-2014|01-02-2014|
```

- if I pass in 01-01-2014 then I expect two rows with IDs 1 and 2 and both to be true (all rows match)
- if I pass in 01-03-2014 then I expect two rows with ID 1 true (match on first row) and ID 2 to be false (because third row is outside of this date)

I am trying to do this in SQL to eventually convert to JPA. If there are any JPA functions that can do this then that would be good to know. Else I'll do a native query

Any pointers would be great!

Thanks

Comment: I dont see in you sample data any date with 01-03-2014

Comment: Do you need the 'FALSE' rows to come back in output, or if the output is limited to just 'TRUE' rows, is that what you want?

Comment: @Mihai exactly there is non 01-03-2014, The null end date means foever into the future so should accept this one

Comment: @ShWiVeL true and false rows are required. Thanks for looking

Comment: Ok was just checking, because in the query I gave if all you cared about was the rows that met your criteria, you could leave out the union / 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want:

```
select x.*, 'PASS' as checker
  from table1 x
 where exists
 (select 'x'
          from table2 y
         where y.table1_id = x.table1_id
           and y.startdate <= '01-01-2014'
           and (y.enddate >= '01-01-2014' or y.enddate is null))
union all
select x.*, 'FAIL' as checker
  from table1 x
 where not exists
 (select 'x'
          from table2 y
         where y.table1_id = x.table1_id
           and y.startdate <= '01-01-2014'
           and (y.enddate >= '01-01-2014' or y.enddate is null))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question.
So, please, be patient... ;)

Try something like this:

```
select t1.id, t1.name,
       case when t2.Table1_ID is null
            then 'false'
            else 'true' end as boolean_value
from Table1 t1,
     (select distinct Table1_ID
      from Table2
      where yourdate >= StartDate
         and (yourdate <= EndDate or EndDate is null) t2
where t1.id = t2.id (+);
```